# Facebook Graph API Photo Upload to a Page shouldn't include into page timeline

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have used the Facebook Graph API for Uploading Image into a Facebook page.
While uploading the image, it publishes into the timeline also.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

Is there any option to preventing to post on the timeline?
What is the "manual_privacy" field do?

Thanks, advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info you are looking for is right there on that page:

> **no_story** - boolean
>
> If set to true, this will suppress the News Feed story that is automatically generated on a profile when people upload a photo using your app. Useful for adding old photos where you may not want to generate a story

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/#Creating